# Not enough gold to buy items in LoD?

Tags: diablo-ii

I have the max amount of gold for my level--2.5 million in my trunk and 860,000 on me.  But the armor I wanted to buy from Larzuk was over 4 million.

If the max gold I can possibly have is about 3.4 million how can I buy armor that costs over 4 million?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to BUY things in D2. The loot you find is way nicer than that bought at vendors.

Comment: Well, two things.  I haven't found that items dropped are as high in defense as the items I find at vendors (the armor defense was much higher than anything I've ever found), and I'm assuming that there must be a way to buy these items or they wouldn't be for sale.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a long time since I played diablo. Are you level 99? If so I guess your only option are those items below.

Comment: I'm curious and want ask what item costs that much.

Comment: It was godly sacred armor.

Answer (score 7):

There are two items that can reduce vendor prices:

- [Gheed's Fortune](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Gheed%27s_Fortune)
- [Edge Runeword](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Edge_Rune_Word)

Together they can reduce vendor prices by up to 30%

Comment: Thanks.  I assume there's no normal way to have enough gold to afford these items then.  Seems strange to sell them at prices that exceed the possible amount of gold one could have.

Comment: If this merchant happens to be in Act II, don't forget to kill Radamant.

Comment: @Ian Larzuk's in act 5, but good point getting the act 2 discount.

Comment: @JamesWinter yeah, seems kind of game breaking but they probably didn't expect you to try and buy 4 million gold armor. To be honest, don't put too much emphasis on defense as in the long run an extra 1000 or so armor won't make much of a difference - since defense only reduces the % chance of being hit, you're better off investing in damage reduction items or life leech if you have a melee character.

Comment: That's interesting--so better defense just decreases the % chance of being hit, but doesn't decrease the damage done when hit?

Comment: @James that is correct.  Physical damage reduction will reduce damage from physical attacks.  Elemental resistance will reduce damage.  But armor is purely for avoiding hits.